# relativelayout align issue about text and image overlap

Tags: android

[image: 4"screen][image: 5"screen]I have the circle icon , it build up by one text view and one image view .

I want text and image can overlap , so i use relativeLayout.

When i run the app , i found it's align out of my control from different screen size.

Is there any better way to design the layout ?

I set the layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PageFragment.ActivityHomePage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityHpEduin"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#66CDAA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityHpTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test" />

        <TextView
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#6666ff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7.16.2016-2/12.2017"
            android:id="@+id/activityHpDate" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/circleNews"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_news" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/circleNews" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleActivityContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/circleNews"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/circleActivityContent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleSignUp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/circleActivityContent"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_apply" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="252dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/circleSignUp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circlePresenter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:src="@drawable/btn_speakers" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/circlePresenter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleHotel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/circlePresenter"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_accommodation" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="138dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/circleHotel" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleTransportation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/circleHotel"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_traffic" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="252dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/circleTransportation" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleSponsor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="117dp"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_sponsors" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="146dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/circleSponsor" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Share expected screenshot.

Comment: any image expected view vs result?

Comment: Ok, i update the screenshot , take a look please. first is 4"screen ,second is 5"screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample code it is similar to what you want.

First here is the xml file code here i have a imageview and below it a text together they are in relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/user_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_email"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The output is like below:
[image]

another answer with new requirement:
xml code:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="119dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/banner_bg" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_universal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="hello world"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

screenshot of above code:
[image]

Remember its a sample code change background path accordingly and other properties.Here there is image and above it there is textview as required.

Comment: thanks for your help , but it's not the screen what i need.

Comment: you wat to add a textview and image view in relative layout where textview is above image view

Comment: Under normal circumstances , i will use linearLayout and layout_weight to handle it , i use relativeLayout because overlapping in this case.

Comment: I found my issue should use relativeLayout in linearLayout , the problem will improve ,  thanks for your help man.

Answer (score 0):

try to bring your textview on front like this
tv_shimmer_tv_gooffline.bringToFront();

Comment: Sorry , i don't know what you mean , my issue is about xml .
What's  tv_shimmer_tv_gooffline.bringToFront(); ?

Comment: you want your textview above imageview in relative layout right?

Comment: More correct is overlapping , and it has the same layout on different screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use SDP. It help me more for such designing to support multiple screen sizes.

SDP - a scalable size unit.

An android SDK that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.

for text views please refer to [ssp](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) which is based on the sp size unit for texts.

https://github.com/intuit/sdp